# how can i get dom elements from html using jQuery's ajax method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have encountered a unique problem. I am doing a simple ajax call using jQuery to get the contents of an html file.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "foo.html",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

foo.html is a simple html file with a main div called #mainContainer. All I want to do is get all of the contents from the mainContainer and store them in a var so i can add them to another div somewhere in my page.

Here's [index.html](http://www.colegillespie.com/code/ajaxTest/) (the file that is making the call).

Here's [foo.html](http://www.colegillespie.com/code/ajaxTest/foo.html) (the file i am trying to call and parse).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery ".load()" API does exactly what you're asking for:

```
$('#the_target_div').load("foo.html #mainContent", function() {
  // stuff to do when content is ready
});
```

You simply add a selector string after the URL, separated by a space.

One thing to note: if the loaded page has any important JavaScript in it (in `<script>` tags), when you load the page that way the scripts will not be run.  If you need that behavior, then you either have to pull out the content yourself (which is a minor mess) or else have your server do the work and respond with only the fragment you need.

A completely different approach would be to load your page into a hidden `<iframe>` and then dive into that DOM to find what you want. It could then be copied into the main page.

Answer (score 2):

var mainContainerInnerHtml = $(data).find("#mainContainer).html();

Answer (score 0):

you do not need get the dom elements.
you can use query replaceWith function to replace.

just like this:

```
$("#data").replaceWith($("#data",ajaxReturnHtml)).serialize();
```

it works to me.